# Why won't myButton.setOnClickListener() take a DialogInterface.OnClickListener as a parameter?

Tags: android, dialog, click, listener

Here's my code:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener( new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


});
```

Which gives me this error:
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

I have DialogInterface and DialogInterface.OnClickListener imported.  "myButton" is in a Dialog.

Here's my current setup.  button1 launches the Dialog, and button2 is contained within the Dialog.

```
private void setOnClickListeners() {
    button1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        //set up dialog
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(WorkScreen.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
        dialog.setTitle("My Dialog");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);    
        dialog.show();

        }

    });

    button2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

This crashes when the Activity loads.  I've also tried moving the Dialog declaration to the top of the class and initializing it in the onCreate, but it didn't change anything.  Ideas?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Like how you are creating the dialog and setting the listener as well.

Comment: Yeah, I put it up as an edit to the original post.  Basically, what I need is one button to launch a Dialog from my Activity, and then I want to handle clicks on the buttons in the Dialog, but I don't know how.  Everything I've tried so far has crashed.  I first tried extending Dialog and setting up the click listeners inside my dialog class, but it was giving me similar errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use DialogInterface.OnClickListener when you need to handle buttons in Dialogs only but View.onclickListener to handle views in an Activiy .

```
class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    Context c ; 
    public MyDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        c = context ; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout) ; 

        Button b3 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3); 
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(c,"Button 3 has been clicked ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



        });

    }


}
```

i create my custom dialog and handle the button in dialog in this class

Comment: When I do it the normal way as a View.OnClickListener, it crashes. The code is within an Activity, but myButton is set on a Dialog that exists within the Activity.

Comment: Yeah, it's up in the original post now.

Comment: It works.  Thank you very much.  I was missing the constructor in my dialog, and I didn't have the proper Context, but now all is well.  Good work!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use DialogInterface.OnClickListener for a button. You should be using [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html).

Comment: When I do it the normal way as a View.OnClickListener, it crashes. The code is within an Activity, but myButton is set on a Dialog that exists within the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Because the setOnClickListener() method of the Button class is expecting a parameter of type View.OnClickListener(), not DialogInterface.OnClickListener();

you should be able to use it this way:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


});
```

Comment: When I do it the normal way as a View.OnClickListener, it crashes.  The code is within an Activity, but myButton is set on a Dialog that exists within the Activity.

Comment: Is the issue that myButton isn't in the layout set to this Activity but is in the layout set to the Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The DialogInterface.OnClickListener is set to the dialog and not the button. When the click event is fired, it passes a 'which' parameter which tells you which button is clicked. To seperately add a click listener to the button, set the View.OnClickListener to it.

Comment: When I do it the normal way as a View.OnClickListener, it crashes. The code is within an Activity, but myButton is set on a Dialog that exists within the Activity.